# How to get values from Java List<E>?

Tags: java, api, remedy

I'm trying to write a mini plugin for the BMC Action Request System Server.

```
filterAPICall
public abstract List<com.bmc.arsys.api.Value> filterAPICall(ARPluginContext context,
                                                        List<com.bmc.arsys.api.Value> pInValues)
                                                 throws com.bmc.arsys.api.ARExceptionDescription copied from interface: ARFilterAPIPluggable
```

Given a set of input values, process it and return a list of output values. The plugin context and instance data are also provided.

```
Specified by:
filterAPICall in interface ARFilterAPIPluggable

Parameters:
context - Current context for this plugin call, like username etc.
pInValues - input values 

Returns:
output values 

Throws: 
com.bmc.arsys.api.ARException
```

The description of com.bmc.arsys.api.Value is here:
http://www.javasystemsolutions.com/documentation/thirdparty/arapiv75/com/bmc/arsys/api/Value.html

Now, here is my call:

```
    public List<Value> filterAPICall(ARPluginContext context, List<Value> pInValues) throws ARException{
        context.logMessage(pluginInfo, ARPluginContext.PLUGIN_LOG_LEVEL_INFO, "filterapiCall()");

        if (pInValues.size() == 0)
            return null;

        ArrayList<Value> outValues = new ArrayList<Value>();

        outValues.add(0, new Value(String.valueOf(InetAddresses.isInetAddress(String.valueOf(pInValues)))));

        return outValues;
    }
```

For some reason

```
    outValues.add(0, new Value(String.valueOf(InetAddresses.isInetAddress(String.valueOf(pInValues)))));
```

is not working.

I've also tried:

```
    outValues.add(0, new Value(String.valueOf(InetAddresses.isInetAddress(String.valueOf(pInValues.getValue())))));
```

but the compiler says:

```
javac IPChecker.java
IPChecker.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getValue()
location: interface java.util.List<com.bmc.arsys.api.Value>
        outValues.add(0, new Value(String.valueOf(InetAddresses.isInetAddress(String.valueOf(pInValues.getValue())))));
                                                                                                      ^
1 error
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be iterating.

```
if (pInValues.size() == 0)
    return null;

ArrayList<Value> outValues = new ArrayList<Value>();

for(Value value : pInValues) {
    outValues.add(0, new Value(String.valueOf(InetAddresses.isInetAddress(String.valueOf(value)))));
}

return outValues;
```

Answer (score 1):

`pInValues` is a [`java.util.List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html). `List`s don't have a `getValue()` method.

Comment: Nor does `String` have a `valueOf()` method for `List`s.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access an element in the `List` to be able to call `getValue()` on it.  Try:

```
outValues.add(0, new Value(String.valueOf(InetAddresses.isInetAddress(
    String.valueOf(pInValues.get(0).getValue())))));
```

This will translate the first element and add it to the output list.  To get all elements, you need to iterate through the elements in `pInValues` and translate them one-by-one, adding each result to the output list